# Query eagerly loading blob in distinct query, how to lazy load?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, hibernate-5.x

ok, here's the exception I get, it's pretty obvious that the problem is trying to load a BLOB into a distinct query. Manually edited the BLOB out of the query and it was fine.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent 
datatypes: expected - got BLOB
```

This is the problematic field, I've been trying to make hibernate not fetch as part of the query.
`Document`

```
@Lob
@LazyGroup( "lob" )
@Fetch( FetchMode.SELECT )
@Basic( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@Column( name = "file_data", nullable = false )
@Type( type = "org.hibernate.type.MaterializedBlobType" )
private byte[] fileData;
```

here's the query in the Spring Data Repository

```
public interface DocumentRepository extends CrudRepository<Document, Long> {

String FIND_DOCUMENTS_WITH_MAPPING = "select distinct assoc.document"
    + " from DocumentAssociation assoc"
    + " where assoc.code.status = 0" // using ordinal to check for active status
    + " order by assoc.document.subsetId asc";

@Query( FIND_DOCUMENTS_WITH_MAPPING )
List<Document> findDocumentsWithMapping();
```

This is the Entity Manager Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@Import( { JpaConfig.class } )
@DependsOn( "jgroupsBindPortProps" )
@Profile( "!" + Profiles.TEST )
public class JpaOracleConfig implements Loggable {

    @Value( "${hibernate.search.default.indexBase}" )
    private String indexBase;

    private static final Stream<String> PROPERTY_KEYS = Stream.of(
        "hibernate.show_sql",
        "hibernate.format_sql",
        "hibernate.session_factory_name",
        "hibernate.session_factory_name_is_jndi",
        "hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache",
        "hibernate.cache.use_query_cache",
        "hibernate.cache.inifinispan.statistics",
        "hibernate.cache.infinispan.cfg",
        "hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.cfg",
        "hibernate.generate_statistics",
        "hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries",
        "hibernate.search.lucene_version",
        "hibernate.search.default.worker.backend",
        "hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use",
        "hibernate.search.services.jgroups.clusterName",
        "hibernate.search.services.jgroups.configurationFile",
        "hibernate.search.default.directory_provider",
        "hibernate.search.infinispan.configuration_resourcename",
        "hibernate.search.default.worker.execution",
        "hibernate.search.default.worker.thread_pool.size",
        "hibernate.search.default.indexBase"
    );

    private final Environment env;

    public JpaOracleConfig( final Environment env ) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    private Map<String, String> jpaPropertyMap() {
        // Needed by infinispan
        // Property hibernate.search.default.indexBase could not be replaced as intended!
        System.setProperty( "hibernate.search.default.indexBase", indexBase );

        final Map<String, String> props = PROPERTY_KEYS.collect( Collectors.toMap(
            Function.identity(),
            env::getProperty
        ) );
        props.put( "hibernate.search.default.indexBase", indexBase );
        props.put( "javax.persistence.validation.mode", ValidationMode.NONE.toString() );
        props.put( "hibernate.search.similarity", IgnoreAllSimilarity.class.getName() );
        props.put( "hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", InfinispanRegionFactory.class.getName() );
        props.put( "hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", Boolean.TRUE.toString() );
        props.put( "hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", Boolean.FALSE.toString() );
        props.put( "hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization", Boolean.TRUE.toString() );
        props.put( "hibernate.enhancer.enableDirtyTracking", Boolean.TRUE.toString() );
        props.put( "hibernate.enhancer.enableExtendedEnhancement", Boolean.TRUE.toString() );
        return props;
    }

    @Primary
    @Profile( "!" + Profiles.TEST )
    @Bean( JpaConfig.EMF )
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
        DataSource dataSource,
        JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter,
        LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver
    ) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf = new DexLocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean( env );
        emf.setDataSource( dataSource );
        emf.setPersistenceUnitName( "persistenceUnit" );
        emf.setPackagesToScan( JpaConfig.PACKAGES );
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter( jpaVendorAdapter );
        emf.setJpaPropertyMap( this.jpaPropertyMap() );
        emf.setLoadTimeWeaver( loadTimeWeaver );
        return emf;
    }
}
```

I believe that enhanced bytecode is working, as when I added the property it blew up until I added `@EnableLoadtimeWeaving` and injected the weaver, and this is in the logs.

```
15:31:54,829 [INFO ] Determined server-specific load-time weaver: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatLoadTimeWeaver [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setBeanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:79) (:)
```

spring boot deps 2.0.3
* hibernate 5.2.x
* spring 5.0.x
* spring data 2.0.x

here's the debug output of my configuration

```
11:37:25,900 [DEBUG] Building session factory                                                              [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:199) (:)
11:37:25,902 [DEBUG] SessionFactory name : defaultSessionFactory                                           [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:69) (:)
11:37:25,902 [DEBUG] Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): enabled                                    [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:70) (:)
11:37:25,903 [DEBUG] Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled                               [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:71) (:)
11:37:25,903 [DEBUG] Statistics: disabled                                                                  [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:73) (:)
11:37:25,903 [DEBUG] Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled                                [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:75) (:)
11:37:25,903 [DEBUG] Default entity-mode: pojo                                                             [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:76) (:)
11:37:25,904 [DEBUG] Check Nullability in Core (should be disabled when Bean Validation is on): enabled    [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:77) (:)
11:37:25,904 [DEBUG] Allow initialization of lazy state outside session : disabled                         [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:78) (:)
11:37:25,904 [DEBUG] Using BatchFetchStyle : LEGACY                                                        [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:80) (:)
11:37:25,904 [DEBUG] Default batch fetch size: -1                                                          [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:81) (:)
11:37:25,904 [DEBUG] Maximum outer join fetch depth: null                                                  [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:82) (:)
11:37:25,905 [DEBUG] Default null ordering: NONE                                                           [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:83) (:)
11:37:25,905 [DEBUG] Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled                                            [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:84) (:)
11:37:25,905 [DEBUG] Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled                                              [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:85) (:)
11:37:25,905 [DEBUG] multi-tenancy strategy : NONE                                                         [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:87) (:)
11:37:25,905 [DEBUG] JTA Track by Thread: enabled                                                          [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:89) (:)
11:37:25,906 [DEBUG] Query language substitutions: {}                                                      [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:91) (:)
11:37:25,906 [DEBUG] JPA query language strict compliance: disabled                                        [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:92) (:)
11:37:25,906 [DEBUG] Named query checking : enabled                                                        [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:93) (:)
11:37:25,906 [DEBUG] Second-level cache: enabled                                                           [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:95) (:)
11:37:25,906 [DEBUG] Second-level query cache: disabled                                                    [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:96) (:)
11:37:25,907 [DEBUG] Second-level query cache factory: org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCacheFactory@7efcc1f6 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:97) (:)
11:37:25,907 [DEBUG] Second-level cache region prefix: null                                                [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:98) (:)
11:37:25,907 [DEBUG] Optimize second-level cache for minimal puts: enabled                                 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:99) (:)
11:37:25,907 [DEBUG] Structured second-level cache entries: enabled                                        [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:100) (:)
11:37:25,907 [DEBUG] Second-level cache direct-reference entries: disabled                                 [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:101) (:)
11:37:25,908 [DEBUG] Automatic eviction of collection cache: disabled                                      [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:102) (:)
11:37:25,908 [DEBUG] JDBC batch size: 15                                                                   [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:104) (:)
11:37:25,908 [DEBUG] JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled                                       [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:105) (:)
11:37:25,908 [DEBUG] Scrollable result sets: enabled                                                       [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:106) (:)
11:37:25,908 [DEBUG] Wrap result sets: disabled                                                            [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:107) (:)
11:37:25,909 [DEBUG] JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): disabled                                                    [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:108) (:)
11:37:25,909 [DEBUG] JDBC result set fetch size: null                                                      [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:109) (:)
11:37:25,909 [DEBUG] Connection release mode: ON_CLOSE                                                     [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:110) (:)
11:37:25,909 [DEBUG] Generate SQL with comments: disabled                                                  [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Settings.<init>(Settings.java:111) (:)
11:37:25,997 [DEBUG] Starting Infinispan region factory                                                    [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:444) (:)
11:37:25,999 [DEBUG] No JtaPlatform was specified, checking resolver                                       [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService(JtaPlatformInitiator.java:42) (:)
11:37:26,000 [DEBUG] No JtaPlatformResolver was specified, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver] [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformResolverInitiator.initiateService(JtaPlatformResolverInitiator.java:33) (:)
11:37:26,023 [DEBUG] Could not resolve JtaPlatform, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform] [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver.resolveJtaPlatform(StandardJtaPlatformResolver.java:110) (:)
11:37:26,026 [DEBUG] Configuration override via property hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.cfg: entity     [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.extractProperty(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:635) (:)
11:37:26,026 [DEBUG] Configuration override via property hibernate.cache.infinispan.cfg: infinispan-l2cache.xml [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.extractProperty(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:635) (:)
11:37:26,439 [WARN ] ISPN000383: The eviction max-entries attribute has been deprecated. Please use the size attribute instead [localhost-startStop-1] org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.Parser80.parseEviction(Parser80.java:1719) (:)
11:37:26,440 [DEBUG] Configuration override via property hibernate.cache.infinispan.statistics: null       [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.extractProperty(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:635) (:)
11:37:27,178 [INFO ] ISPN000078: Starting JGroups channel ISPN                                             [localhost-startStop-1] org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.start(JGroupsTransport.java:188) (:)
```

and the field processing shows this

```
11:37:22,286 [DEBUG] MetadataSourceProcessor property fileData with lazy=true                           [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makePropertyAndValue(PropertyBinder.java:175) (:)
11:37:22,286 [DEBUG] Attempting to locate auto-apply AttributeConverter for property [com.myapp.Document:fileData] [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.AbstractPropertyHolder.resolveAttributeConverterDescriptor(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:95) (:)
11:37:22,286 [DEBUG] building SimpleValue for fileData                                                  [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.SimpleValueBinder.make(SimpleValueBinder.java:411) (:)
11:37:22,287 [DEBUG] Building property fileData                                                         [localhost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.PropertyBinder.makeProperty(PropertyBinder.java:266) (:)
```

How can I change my code such that `fileData` will only be fetched if requested?

Answer (score 0):

give up, I have not been able to figure out how to make this work, got build time weaving working... sort of, but that 'caused all sorts of spectacular errors on startup completely unrelated to this. My solution, remove this field from the entity and in a case where it's supposed to be used, but really lazily, I came up with this... hack... and passed the supplier around.

```
@Query( value = "SELECT file_data FROM document where id = ?", nativeQuery = true )
Blob getDocumentData( long id );

/* I am an evil method written to preserve prior contracts */
static Supplier<InputStream> getDocumentDataById( long id ) {
    return () -> {
        try {
            return SpringHelper.getBean( DocumentRepository.class )
                .getDocumentData( id )
                .getBinaryStream();
        }
        catch ( SQLException e ) {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger( DocumentRepository.class ).error( "data not retrieved {}", e );
        }
        return new ByteArrayInputStream( new byte[0] );
    };
}
```